# Selenium immediately returns the result from second request on

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, request

I'm now writing a script to download a file on a website, on Python (3.6) and Selenium using Firefox as its driver. But while the download on the first request succeeds, when I send out the second request, the driver immediately gets returned. For example,

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get(url)
try:
    download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='download']/span")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download_button)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No such file exists")

driver.close()
```

In this case, when I first sends out the request, the script above works. But from my second request on on the same driver, the download does not work since the `driver.get(url)` immediately gets returned, and thus before the page finishes to be loaded, the `try ~ except` clause starts, which naturally does not find the xpath component, triggering `NoSuchElementException` error.

I think there is a better way, but I don't like to open a new driver on each page, as it uses up so much of computer resources (which actually is my current script). Another workaround might be the use of `driver.implicitly_wait(30)`, but I'm not sure if the page load finishes within 30 seconds, and rather want to start the download just after the page finishes to be loaded, which is the case on my first request.

Is there any way to archive this?

Comment: Try with an explicit wait with Expected Condition (element_to_be_clickable) on the download_button

Comment: Any reason to avoid the _proven_ and _powerful_ **click()** and use `execute_script()` ?

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry if I got it worng but is it different from what I did? I used `click()` within `execute_script()`.

Comment: The `click()` you used within `execute_script()` method is the **Javascript** `click()` leaving out the **WebDriver** [`click()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) which is proven and powerful. My question is _why so_?